# Invalid HEX number while inserting UUID

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

In oracle I have a DOC_ID column

```
RAW(16) for my UUID/GUID
```

in hibernate I mapped it this way

```
@ID
@GeneratedValue(Generator= "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy="uuid2")
@Type(type="uuid-char")
@Column(name="DOC_ID", unique= true)
private UUID id;
```

during insertion, it keeps complaining ORA-01465: invalid hex number.

May I know what is that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A char representation of a UUID is 36 chars, whereas the binary representation is 16 bytes. Try with

```
@Type(type="uuid-binary")
```

instead of

```
@Type(type="uuid-char")
```