# JPA UUID mapping for Oracle ORA-01465: invalid hex number

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jpa

While this mapping works in MySQL on saving objects:

```
@Id
private String id;
```

on Oracle it throws: `ORA-01465: invalid hex number when I am saving my object.`

This is how I create id: `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

My app must support both MySQL 5 and Oracle 12. So I can add only some mysql / oracle specific adapters / extensions that could be easily turned off while switching from one db to another. I cannot change JPA entities code if that would mean binding them to specific database. It must work on both databases.

What could I do so that it wouldn't break the application while switching from one MySQL to Oracle ?

Comment: see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985893/invalid-hex-number-while-inserting-uuid

Comment: How does the table definition look like?

Comment: @Type(type="uuid-binary") would work on Oracle but not on MySQL ? The table definition ID    NOT NULL RAW(16 BYTE)  and I can change that as I want. RAW is generated from liquibase changelog which has uuid as id type on this entity. <column name="id" type="uuid"> it works with Mysql. I could change it to char(36) and it would be the same in Oracle and Mysql then because liquibase does this in Mysql: 'id', 'char(36)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''

Answer (score 0):

Just remove '-' from UUID.randomUUID().toString()
For example,

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-","")
```